# Rails: Time lock on record update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to time lock updates on a specific record. I'm using the acts_as_votable gem and want to allow an upvote only every 3 or 5 minutes.

The column `updated_at` gets a new timestamp whenever the record gets updated through an upvote.

I tried to achieve this through validation (or better `before_save`?) and this code snippet in my model:

`errors.add(:base, "Try again later.") if self.updated_at < (DateTime.now - 5.minutes)`

But this actually isn't working. Do you guys have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please give more informations about the models you are using. Where do you set `errors`

Comment: You might (and answers might) have the `<` the wrong way round. You want to trigger the error when the updated_at is more recent, i.e. `>` than the current time minus 5 minutes.

Comment: Hai @harakiri, have you reversed the condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello take a custom method on validation and get the previous value from db using `field_name_was` method.

Call a method in validations which we are going to write.

`validate :updated_at_validation`

```js
def updated_at_validation 
 old_date = self.updated_at_was 
 if old_date > (DateTime.now - 5.minutes) 
  errors.add(:updated_at, "can't be changed in less than 5 minutes") 
 end 
end
```

In your controller,

```js
def vote 
 if @feature_request.update_attributes(:updated_at => DateTime.now) 
  @feature_request.vote_by voter: current_user, :duplicate => true 
  redirect_to :back 
 else 
  redirect_to feature_requests_url, alert: 'cant be changed in less than 5 minutes' 
 end 
end
```

Thats it your custom validation is set.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to compare to the saved value, not the new one.
Try something like this:

```
self.updated_at_was < (DateTime.now - 5.minutes)
```

Comment: Could you try to compare `updated_at` and `updated_at_was`. There should be a difference.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've seen in the code on [1] the votes will be saves as relation in every time a new record. Therefor it is useless to try to use the updated_at
as indicator of a change.

You should try to find the latest vote by requesting the vote table to get 
the important informations and then act.

[1] https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable/tree/master/lib/acts_as_votable

Comment: Strange, but the updated_at gets updated as well every time.